# HTML able to change text size but not color

Tags: html

I have a simple table of hyperlinks:

```
<ul id="toc">
<font size="6" color="red">
<a href="http://www.afakesitename.com/page1.html">Page 1</a>
<a href="http://www.afakesitename.com/page2.html">Page 2</a>
<a href="http://www.afakesitename.com/page3.html">Page 3</a>
</font>
</ul>
```

I am able to change the font size of the table entries (e.g. "Page 1") by altering the "size", however the color remains blue regardless of the value for "color".

What is the error in my code or my approach?

Comment: Don't use `<font>` - use CSS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to access element to give it a color

```html
<style>
a{
  color: red;
}
</style>
<ul id="toc">
<font size="6" color="red">
<a href="http://www.afakesitename.com/page1.html">Page 1</a>
<a href="http://www.afakesitename.com/page2.html">Page 2</a>
<a href="http://www.afakesitename.com/page3.html">Page 3</a>
</font>
</ul>
```

Edit: Dont use font tag because font tag is not supported in HTML5. Use CSS instead.

```html
<style>
  a{
  color: red;
  font-size: 26px;
  text-decoration: none:
}
</style>
<ul id="toc">
<a href="http://www.afakesitename.com/page1.html">Page 1</a>
<a href="http://www.afakesitename.com/page2.html">Page 2</a>
<a href="http://www.afakesitename.com/page3.html">Page 3</a>
</ul>
```

Comment: thank you both. @joe_young, with your second "better" method, it appears the styles are still being explicitly stated for each line? I have tried this and I can control color but not font size. Have I misunderstood?

Comment: I didnt get what are you trying to tell me ? can you explain more ?

Comment: Sorry never mind, I was trying joe_youngs, but your second works for me so I've used that now. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You should use **[CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS)** instead
You can use inline styles by using the `style` attribute

```html
<ul id="toc">
    <a href="http://www.afakesitename.com/page1.html" style="font-size: 6; color: red;">Page 1</a>
    <a href="http://www.afakesitename.com/page2.html" style="font-size: 6; color: red;">Page 2</a>
    <a href="http://www.afakesitename.com/page3.html" style="font-size: 6; color: red;">Page 3</a>
</ul>
```

However, inlining styles as above isn't the best practice.
Instead, you should put your CSS in an external CSS file, or use the `<style>` tag:

```css
<style>
    #toc a {
        font-size: 6;
        color: red;
    }
</style>
```

```html
<ul id="toc">
  <a href="http://www.afakesitename.com/page1.html" style="font-size: 6; color: red;">Page 1</a>
  <a href="http://www.afakesitename.com/page2.html" style="font-size: 6; color: red;">Page 2</a>
  <a href="http://www.afakesitename.com/page3.html" style="font-size: 6; color: red;">Page 3</a>
</ul>
```